# Missing Doxygen Executable for GROMACS on Linux

Tags: simulation, doxygen, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm attempting to install GROMACS on Linux for my Masters Project. I've followed the instructions given in this guide https://github.com/rehanzfr/MDSimulations/blob/master/README.md, I’ve gotten to nearly the final step, running the line:

`sudo cmake .. -DGMX_BUILD_OWN_FFTW=OFF -DREGRESSIONTEST_DOWNLOAD=OFF -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc -DREGRESSIONTEST_PATH=/home/username/Downloads/GromacsDownload/regressiontests-2020`

However I’ve fallen at the final hurdle and I’m getting the error:

```
-- Doxygen not found. Documentation targets will not be generated.
CMake Error at tests/CMakeLists.txt:103 (message):
  REGRESSIONTEST_PATH invalid.  The path needs to contain gmxtest.pl.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/er/Downloads/GromacsDownload/gromacs-2020/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/er/Downloads/GromacsDownload/gromacs-2020/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

This is my first time using GROMACS, Linux, and installing software this way. So although I'm fairly confident there's some library I'm missing (possibly more errors too). I'm not sure how to find it, install it, or even where the correct place to put it is.

Any help on how to solve these problems would be greatly appreciated, or if the guide I'm following is incorrect, how to start again and install GROMACS correctly.

NB: I've been through the install guide on the GROMACS website, but it assumes a level of familiarity beyond my ability.

Thank you in advance, and please let me know if you require more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what GROMACS but probably the following will shine a little light on it.

Doxygen is in principle not a library but a program that has to be installed, so either a version is available for you platform (might not be the most current version of doxygen though, the current version is 1.9.1) and you can install it directly by means of an `apt-get` call otherwise you have to download a the sources from https://www.doxygen.nl/download.html or get the sources directly from the repository at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen. After you have the sources you can build with cmake / make / install your doxygen version and use it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Could I ask how I'd use apt-get? I tried typing "sudo apt-get Doxygen" but apparently thats an invalid command. Also, does it matter which directory I install Doxygen to?

Comment: I think you have to do `sudo apt-get install doxygen` (but it might be another name as well, but have a look at e.g. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-install-doxygen-on-ubuntu or search the internet for `sudo apt-get install doxygen`. I cannot try it as I don't have a system with apt-get). When the installation process is correct it should add doxygen to your path and after opening a new terminal window it should work out of the box )(of course you have to rerun cmake).